# MySQL Workbench High DPI

Tags: fonts, mysql-workbench, dpi

So I'm using MySQL workbench in a new high DPI, high resolution setting.  If I allow MySQL Workbench to use Window's DPI settings, the font becomes blurry everywhere but the editor.

If I disable the DPI settings (in Compatibility) and raise the font size in the Workbench Preferences, it looks fine except for the left menu (schema list, table list, object info) which is very small font.  Does anyone know of any workaround or an alternative to Workbench?  It's going to be hard to continue using Workbench with a high resolution display otherwise.  HeidiSQL suffered the same DPI blurry font problem.  So it's either headache or squinting.

Comment: There's partial support for hidpi rendering, especially on Mac. On Windows things are much more complicated because Windows has no stringent handling for high resolution monitors/output. It will certainly take quite some time yet until this is solved.

Comment: @MikeLischke : Thanks.  Most all Windows apps in 8 look great at high DPI.  The few that aren't are usually Oracle based unfortunately:  Java and Workbench it seems.   It's nice that they allow you to adjust the font size of the editor but seems kind of pointless if you can't adjust all the fonts.

Comment: Exactly. Aside from Java apps and the Workbench, everything else got updated and looks georgeous. And it's not like high DPI displays are anything new, they've been around for the Windows platform for more than 2 years now.

Comment: Well not really address your question, but this is why I started using Data Grip, the JetBrains equivalent. Plus is a lot less buggy

Comment: Is a known [bug known... since 2009](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48867)! _Bug #48867 MySQL Workbench is not dpi-aware_

Comment: I'd recommend HeidiSQL with the Material Theme.  Personally, it does anything I could ask for out of an SQL client.

Comment: @Devon I tried HeidiSQL and I liked the functionality but it doesn't support HiDPI.

Answer (score 18):

I am using windows 10, right clicking on the executable and clicking Troubleshoot compatibility did not work for me. Ticking "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:", then choose "System (Enhanced)". did not help too.

What i did is:
"Change high DPI sttings" and tick "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:", then choose "Application". Click "Ok" then "Apply"

Comment: This worked great and solved the problem. MySql Workbench 8.

Comment: But menu and other fonts are very small

Comment: Worked for me! Override high DPI scaling behavior -> Scaling performed by: "Application" 

Answer (score 13):

I am using Windows 10 Pro, after the Creators upgrade, and a 4K 27" monitor. Right-click on the MySQL Workbench program icon, choose "Compatibility", then tick "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:", then choose "System (Enhanced)". That makes it look reasonable, although the table names are still pixel-doubled so they look fuzzy, and the Output windows still uses a small font.

Comment: I used the troubleshooter for this (on Windows 10 Pro, right click on the executable --> "Troubleshoot compatibility") and it did the trick. The first time a Windows troubleshooter actually solved a problem!

Comment: The above comment should be the answer. It works fine now nothing is pixelated.

Comment: thanks @balt. I have been searching on the web for over an hour, and your trick work very well in year 2020.

Comment: Still looks blurry with this setting.

Answer (score 7):

To Fix the resolution and make mysql showing up in a high Quality on Windows 10

1. Right click on the Mysql Icon where you run your application
2. Properties
3. Choose "Compatibility"
4. Change high DPI scaling Settings
5. and Finally Tick on "Override high DPI scaling behavior"
6. Close your app if it's Running and re Lunch it to see the Different.
   Enjoy :D

Answer (score 2):

**Linux Specific**

This is likely not a solution if you are using the EER-Diagram feature which is likely using some custom drawing routines.

MySQL-Workbench is using [Gtk 3](https://www.gtk.org) which is supporting HighDPI-Displays and the modern Wayland-Protocol well. It shall work but the UI doesn't scale on Wayland. The responsible desktop entry launches actually a script named *mysql-workbench* which itself launches the actual *mysql-workbench-bin*. We need to keep using it because MySQL-Workbench has some weird requirements:

```bash
1 #!/bin/bash
2 
3 # Uncomment the following line if you're having trouble with gnome-keyring lockups.
4 # This will cause passwords to be stored only temporarily for the session.
5 #WB_NO_GNOME_KEYRING=1
6 
7 # force disable the Mac style single menu hack in Ubuntu Unity
8 export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
9 
10 # another Ubuntu bug, this this one causes modal dialogs to not work as intended
11 # https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/903302
12 export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
13 
14 # force x11 backend on systems that use wayland
15 export GDK_BACKEND=x11
16 
17 # Set the destdir=<some_dir> when ever you install using DESTDIR=<some_dir>. 
18 destdir="$WB_DEST_DIR"
19 
20 wblibdir="$destdir/usr/lib/mysql-workbench"
21 wbpluginsdir="$destdir/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/plugins"
22 ...
23 ...
24 ...
```

Copy the script and comment out the line with `export GDK_BACKEND=x11` and use it. Now it should render an appropriate UI. A segfault upon quit seems normal. For a more convenient solution:

1. Copy and edit the script as above
2. Store the script where you prefer e.g. as hidden dotfile
3. Copy `/usr/share/applications/mysql-workbench.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/mysql-workbench.desktop` # it overrides the global
4. Edit the desktop file and point `Exec=mysql-workbench %f` to your modified script

*Notes*
The line which forces the X11 backend doesn't note why it is used. Another approach would be enforcing a integral scaling factor by `$ GDK_BACKEND=2 name_of_your_executable` or falling back  to [fractional scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Fractional_scaling). I guess similar restrictions apply on Mac and Windows and are the cause for the problems.